# Could accept attribute validate?

Tags: html, validation

Would Html5 accept attribute validate? What I mean is, If we give< `input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/jpg" />` will it accepts only jpg file>. Or Should i use javascript to validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_accept.asp

> Tip: Do not use this attribute as a validation tool. File uploads
>   should be validated on the server.